# waiting for Promise in a Loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach

Using AngularJs, when using a forEach Loop, the variable outside the loop still always 0: 
to explain my problem, this is my code

```
var totald=0;
   children.forEach(function (child) {
                   fetchdata(child['id']).then(function (resp) {
                    totald+= resp.total;
                    domaines.push({'id': child['id'], 'total': resp.total, 'details': resp.details});

                });

                });
```

After forEach, when I do console.log(totald), I get 0. but when I put console.log inside the forEach, the variable totald is incremented.

How I can resolve the problem and get  the correct value of totald after the forEach finishied

Comment: Can you merge your promises with [`$q.all()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all)?

Comment: or you might need recursion of promises.. :P

Comment: @js_noob not the best idea to have nested / chained promises with dynamic data (when you don't know how many elements are in the array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can map each promise as a list and await all of them using `$q.all`.

Something like this:

```
var totald = 0;
var promises = children.map(function (child) {
    return fetchdata(child['id']).then(function(response){
        return { id: child['id'], response: response };
    });
});

$q.all(promises).then(function(results)){
    results.forEach(function(result){
        totald += result.response.total;
        domaines.push({'id': result.id, 'total': result.response.total, 'details': result.response.details});
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider rewritting this code in a functional style; it will be much more readable:

```
const promises = children.map(async (child) => {
  const response = await fetchdata(child['id']);
  return { 
    id: child['id'], 
    response 
  };
});

const results = await Promise.all(promises);

const total = results.map(result => result.response.total)
  .reduce((x, y) => x + y, 0);

const domains = results.map(result => ({
  id: result.id, 
  total: result.response.total, 
  details: result.response.details
});
```

The most significant change is using `map` instead of `forEach`. There is never really a reason to use `forEach` because the `for (... of ...)` construct more clearly suggests side-effects. `map` is also more compact:

```
const ys = xs.map(x => x + 1);
```

vs...

```
const ys = [];
xs.forEach(x => {
  ys.push(x + 1);
})
```

If you are concerned about browser-support for async-await then you can use Babel + Webpack.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Promise.all:

```js
var total = 0;            
Promise.all(
    children.map(function(c) { return fetchdata(child['id']); })
).then(function(datas) {
    datas.forEach(function(data) {
        total += data.total;
        domaines.push({'id': child['id'], 'total': data.total, 'details': data.details});    
    });
});
```

Comment: It's better to use AngularJS's `$q` promise, since it will be evaluated during the $digest cycle