# How to execute a promise first and then move to the next statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

What I want to do is wait for the second promise to finish, concatenate the data i.e `data = data.concat(items)` and then increment the count making the loop run specified times. It's all written in AngularJS.

```
DataService.getSomeData().then(function(data) {
  let count = 1;
  while (count < 3) {
    if (someCondition) { // It evaluates to true

      // Second Promise
      DataService.getUserData().then(function(items) {
        data = data.concat(items); // --------> this should run before incrementing the count
      });

      count++;
    }
    $scope.myData = data;
  }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try: `DataService.getUserData().then((items)=>{...}).finally(()=>{count++;});`. But since it's a loop, it's better to work with `$q.all()` to merge promises and resolve them in sync

Comment: have you tried with `await`?

Comment: @Kaddath Cannot use async await

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Could you please demonstrate how can I do this using $q.all(). I looked at a few examples but couldn't understand what to do exactly.

Comment: @AjayGupta here is a similar question that was asked an hour ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48111247/waiting-for-promise-in-a-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the api returning promises - its the easiest to handle and most predictable...

```
  DataService.getSomeData()
    .then(someData => {
        let count = 1;
        const promises = [];

        while (count < 3) {
            if (someCondition) { // It evaluates to true
                promises.push(DataService.getUserData());
                count++;
            }
        }

        return $q.all(promises)
            .then(data => data.reduce((memo, data) => memo.concat(data), someData));
    })
    .then(data => $scope.myData = data);
```

Answer (score 1):

@Aleksey Solovey has already mentioned the solution which is to use $q.all(), there is another method of recursion which you can make use of.

```
DataService.getSomeData().then(function(data) {
  getUserDataRecursion(data,0).then(result=>{
    $scope.myData = result;
  }).catch(error=>{
    console.log("error handle ",error)
  })
});


getUserDataRecursion(data,count){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    if(count<3){
      if (someCondition){
        DataService.getUserData().then((items) {
          data = data.concat(items);
          count++;
          getUserDataRecursion(data,count),then(()=>{
            resolve(data);
          })
        });
      }else{
        resolve(data);
      }
    }else{
      resolve(data);
    }
  })
}
```